# How to sanitization form fields in node js

Tags: node.js, express, sanitize

I have installed package express-validator and want to sanitize form fields, but sanitize is not working and showing error:  TypeError: req.sanitize is not a function

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {    
console.log(req.sanitize(req.body.name));
    let name = req.sanitize(req.body.name);
});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: req.sanitize is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the dependency at all. Sanitize is not part of the request object in express.

You also have to create your sanitize object of what you are trying to validate.

https://express-validator.github.io/docs/

```
// ...rest of the initial code omitted for simplicity.
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

app.post(
  '/user',
  // username must be an email
  body('username').isEmail(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  body('password').isLength({ min: 5 }),
  (req, res) => {
    // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    User.create({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
    }).then(user => res.json(user));
  },
);
```